# regex to find if there are more than 2 same words

Tags: expression

i am new to regex.
if there are more than 2 same words match it or show it.

ex:
124@abc.com , 345@abc.com,.........................

Comment: Can you share what regex you have tried already? And what language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked a general question, I can only give you a general answer. Adding /g at the end of your expression will stand for global match. Meaning that it will find all occurrences of your expression.